# is it possible to test on a Moto X4 Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

A client who is using our Android app is having problems. He is using a Moto X4 Android. He is the only client experiencing this problem, so it seems like it is his phone type which is the problem. Is it possible to create an Moto X4 Android emulator?

Here is what I tried - I looked through the AVD in Android Studio but I did not find it.

I then looked to see if there was some kind of downloads but  didnt find anything.